# I am trying to pass a print instruction if an item is not in a list in python. It is working for only when the pin is wrong not for wrong account

Tags: python

```
account_name = ['Adetunji Michael', 'Dina Asher-Smith', 'Niyola Davidson', 'John Paul']
valid_accounts= [3455590445, 2871290429, 3599076267, 1234567890]
valid_pins = [34777, 45786, 24055, 12345]
account_balance= [112000, 45700, 2300, 30000]

#This is the introductory aesthetic.
print("             *************************")
print("                 ABC BANK OF NIGERIA.\n              MARVELLING YOU SINCE 2003\n             WELCOME TO THE ATM MACHINE.")
print("             *************************")

#This is the start of the code. Everything here is made on the inference that normal ATM machines do not have any alphabetic input available.

trials=3
while trials!=0:
    account= int(input("    PLEASE INPUT YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER: "))
    pin = int(input("   PLEASE INPUT YOUR 5 DIGIT PIN: "))
    correct_pin= valid_pins[valid_accounts.index(account)]
    if (account not in valid_accounts) or (pin!=correct_pin):
        print(" INVALID LOGIN DETAILS. ")
        trials= trials-1
        print(" YOU HAVE ", trials, " TRIALS LEFT")
    elif (account in valid_accounts) and (pin==correct_pin):
        print("Welcome")
```

Comment: You need to `break` out of the loop on success.

Comment: Also, you should check for `correct_pin` after you have verified a correct `account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trials=3
while trials!=0:
    account= int(input("    PLEASE INPUT YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER: "))
    pin = int(input("   PLEASE INPUT YOUR 5 DIGIT PIN: "))
    correct_pin= valid_pins[valid_accounts.index(account)]
    if (account not in valid_accounts) or (pin!=correct_pin):
        print(" INVALID LOGIN DETAILS. ")
        trials= trials-1
        print(" YOU HAVE ", trials, " TRIALS LEFT")
    elif (account in valid_accounts) and (pin==correct_pin):
        print("Welcome")
        break
```

But the program will have some uncovered cases still

- If the inputted account is not in the account list you'll get ValueError.
- Converting input() into int() immediately is not a very good practice. if a string is inputted you'll get a ValueError.

---

### Edit:

```
trials=3
while trials!=0:
        try: # Check if the input is convertible to int()
            account= int(input("    PLEASE INPUT YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER: "))
            pin = int(input("   PLEASE INPUT YOUR 5 DIGIT PIN: "))

            if account in valid_accounts:
                    # Create correct_pin only after making sure that the account is in valid_accounts.
                    #  Otherwise .index() will not work
                    correct_pin= valid_pins[valid_accounts.index(account)]
                    # You need to check the correct pin only when the account is valid
                    # Makes no sence to check the pin if there is no such account.
                    if (pin==correct_pin): 
                            print("Welcome")
                            break
                    else: # Pin is either correct or not. Else is more suitable than elif.
                            print(" INVALID LOGIN DETAILS. ")
                            trials -= 1
                            print(" YOU HAVE ", trials, " TRIALS LEFT")

            else: # Account is either valid or not. Else is more suitable than elif.
                    print(" INVALID LOGIN DETAILS. ")
                    trials -= 1
                    print(" YOU HAVE ", trials, " TRIALS LEFT")
                    
    except ValueError:
            print("   PLEASE INPUT ONLY INTEGERS")
```

Comment: Thank you. Any recommendation for how to make my code print invalid login details if the inputted account number is not in the list. I thought the not in function would do that

Comment: @Chukwukelu Marvelous, I edited the answer. You'll need to make some structural changes in the logic. Please see the comments in the code.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The code is now running perfectly. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Glad that it works. Consider accepting the answer if your question has been exhausted. Cheers!